# Quick question on simplifying expression with summation in it

Tags: probability, summation

This is from Hoel, Port, Stone:

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

I don't see how they simplified the $(1 - \frac{k}{r})^n$ from (15) and $(1 - \frac{j}{r-k})^n$ term from the last expression in (13) with the upper limit as $r-k$, instead of $r$, to end up with $(1 - \frac{j+k}{r})^n$. I may be overlooking something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(1-\frac{j}{r-k}\right)\left(1-\frac{k}{r}\right)=\left(\frac{r-k-j}{r-k}\right)\left(\frac{r-k}{r}\right)=\frac{r-k-j}{r}=1-\frac{j+k}{r}.$$

Comment: Oh wow. For some reason I totally blanked on $x^zy^z = (xy)^z$. Thanks!